# iframe session issue for the first time

Tags: php, internet-explorer

i am having some application in PHP and providing service to some other client. they have put our link in the `iframe` on their site page. The problem is with session establishment. it works great in google chrome , firefox and `IE 8`. but it is creating a problem in `IE 9`. For the first time, when the page is opened , the session is not established on our application but if the page is refreshed then the session is established.

IF i copy the `iframe` link to the `IE9` address bar, then also the session is established. I have not used any domain for our application just given them the public IP to be used.

For session , the client is sending its details along with our page and we authenticate and establish the session on our server. Our session is different than the session used by client. The application is hosted our own server.

Comment: Please post in how/where are you declaring session?

Comment: I have found a solution. It is due to P3P policies. I have included the line shown below. But the i have heard that we cannot directly use P3P policies like that. It comes under legal bailment. Does the IDC comes under legal bailment. header('P3P:CP="IDC"');

Comment: But it is not working on safari browser??